# Is there a way to use CloudFront signed cookies in HTML

Tags: cookies, amazon-s3

I'm trying to just get started in my understanding on how the CloudFront with signed cookies work.

I have an HTML file that is tied to my CloudFront distribution:

```
http://blahblahbla.cloudfront.net/lebron.jpg
```

If I'm reading the instructions properly I have to add something to my Bucket policy for my S3 bucket that I'm using as the origin:

```
{
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Resource":"base URL or stream name",
         "Condition":{
            "DateLessThan":{
               "AWS:EpochTime":ending date and time in Unix time format and UTC
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

After that it looks like I have to add the following to somewhere:

```
Set-Cookie: Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Expires=1426500000
Set-Cookie: Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Signature=yXrSIgyQoeE4FBI4eMKF6ho~CA8_
Set-Cookie: Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKA9ONS7QCOWEXAMPLE
```

The above is from the documentation.  Do I add the above in between my `<head>` tags or somewhere else?

I see a lot of documentation for Python and even C# but i'm just trying to do a simple test using the signed cookies with a simple HTML page.  Is that even possible?

It goes without saying that, I'm still pretty far from understanding this, so any help regarding the Bucket policy and the keys issue would be appreciated.